# Lift doesn't like my Web.xml

Tags: java, tomcat, scala, lift

I am having trouble with a basic hello world lift application from working under tomcat 6.0.18. My web.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE web-app
        PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
        "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>LiftFilter</filter-name>
        <display-name>Lift Filter</display-name>
        <description>The Filter that intercepts lift calls</description>
        <filter-class>net.liftweb.http.LiftFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>LiftFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


</web-app>
```

But when I start up the app, I get

```
INFO: Starting service Catalina Jan 18, 2011 7:42:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start 
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.18 Jan 18, 2011 7:42:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig defaultWebConfig 
INFO: No default web.xml
Jan 18, 2011 7:42:45 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start 
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-9981 Jan 18, 2011 7:42:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start 
INFO: Server startup in 1275 ms
```

Which leads me to believe it doesn't like my web.xml.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ***default*** web.xml (in the conf directory) seems to be missing, you web.xml should be OK providing it's in the WEB-INF folder of course.

Comment: You got it. Nothing to do with scala or lift, just with me breaking the tomcat conf directory.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is saying that it cannot **find** your `web.xml` file.  Is it in the following location when your WAR file is expanded?

```
$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/yourApp/WEB-INF/web.xml
```

Comment: It is there inside the war, yes